# jQuery not responding when Submit input type is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm simply trying to get an event to run when a button is clicked in my HTML. Currently, nothing occurs except the page reloads.

**HTML**

```
<form id="existing_queries_and_dates">
    <div id="search_dates">
        <h3>Available Dates</h3>
        <select id="date_range">
            {% for date in date_range %}
            <option value="{{date}}">{{date}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type="submit" id="submit_query_date_combo" value="Re-Load Table">
    </div>
</form>
```

and my **Javascript** (this is the *only* code in the file. I know the files are linked correctly so that shouldn't be the issue):

```
$("#submit_query_date_combo").on("click", function(){
    console.log("Submitted!");
    alert("HIasd");
});
```

I don't get any errors, but I also don't get the alert or console.log.

If I remove the `form` tags, the page doesn't reload anymore, but I still don't get the alert or console.log

Comment: Where in relation to your body is this script?  Also is anything in regards to the form created dynamically?

Comment: @Taplar - OH DUH!  I have the script importing at the top. I just moved to the bottom (right before `</body>`) and it works. Thanks so much for that simple reminder.  You can throw that in to an answer. (...or should I just delete this thread since the issue at hand has nothing to do with the HTML/.js itself?)

Answer (score 0):

Since your `submit` button is inside the `form` you need to use `preventDefault()` to avoid form submission when button is clicked:

```
$("#submit_query_date_combo").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Submitted!");
    alert("HIasd");
});
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't work. Nothing happens still, no errors either.  Edit: It was due to where I was bringing in the .js file. I moved to right before `</body>` and it works now.

Comment: This is only half the problem, as the question notes that removing the form does not cause the logic to execute.

Comment: Is your javascript code inside `$(function() {})` or `$(document).ready() `?

Comment: @SevaKalashnikov - No. Should it all be ?

Comment: It depends on if you going to manipulate the dom or not, as for now it shouldn't matter, but if you want to execute your even listener events after html and css is fully rendered you will need to wrap it in `$(function() {})` @BruceWayne

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are running your javascript before the DOM is loaded, and because of that the click event handler is not attached to the DOM element because it does not find it. I would suggest you to add a  handler for `DOMContentLoaded` event and then attach your DOM event handlers, like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    $("#submit_query_date_combo").on("click", function(ev){
        console.log("Submitted!");
        alert("HIasd");
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="existing_queries_and_dates">
    <div id="search_dates">
        <h3>Available Dates</h3>
        <select id="date_range">
            <option value="0">0</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" id="submit_query_date_combo" value="Re-Load Table">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your jquery is working or not and if not then add cdn of jquery. and also you can convert your input type submit to input type button and submit your form on button click . Change date dropdown values accordingly you.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit_query_date_combo').on('click',function(){
        console.log("Submitted!");
            alert("HIasd");
             $('#existing_queries_and_dates').submit();
         });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="existing_queries_and_dates">
        <div id="search_dates">
            <h3>Available Dates</h3>
            <select id="date_range">         
                <option value="0">0</option>            
            </select>
            <input type="button" id="submit_query_date_combo" value="Re-Load Table">
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```